# rCharts and gvisMotionChart are not displayed when published in rPubs

Tags: r, rstudio, ggvis, rpres

I have made a rpresenter file. The code is displayed below. When I published in rPubs, slides with words are displayed. But the motion charts and other charts are not displayed, showing: 
AccessDeniedAccess Denied573371FF628EBE0CmrHb5GPTc+1Ul1K15psqFpJ/f6dovc+frwQougDVtROA6ZQajWyye0Jr9CvH

I had gone through the RStudio documentation. I was wondering how to display the charts properly. Thanks in anticipation.

````
 Presentation On Datasets
 ========================================================
 author: Harry
 date: 8/27/2016
 autosize: true


 Selecting The Data
  ========================================================

 ### We will select the diamonds dataset available in package 'ggplot2'.       
 Lets look at the data.

 ```{r}
 library(ggplot2)
 head(diamonds)
 ```

 Summary Of Data
 ========================================================


  ### Lets view the summary of data

  ```{r}
  library(ggplot2)
  summary(diamonds)

   ```


   Charts
  ========================================================

  ### Lets display some charts.

   ```{r results = 'asis', comment = NA}
   library(rCharts)
   library(ggplot2)

   n1 <- nPlot(carat ~ cut , group = "color", data = diamonds[1:40,], type =   "multiBarChart")
  n1

  ```


  Plot
  =============================================================

  ### Plotting Chart from economics dataset

  ```{r results = 'asis', comment = NA}
  library(rCharts)
  data(economics, package = 'ggplot2')
  econ <- transform(economics, date = as.character(date))
  m1 <- mPlot(x = 'date', y = c('psavert', 'uempmed'), type = 'Line',data = econ)
  m1$set(pointSize = 0, lineWidth = 1)
  m1

  ```

 Plot
 ============================================================

   ### Lets plot some Geographical Data

   ```{r gvisMergeExample, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
   library(googleVis)
   Geo <- gvisGeoChart(Exports, locationvar='Country', colorvar='Profit',
                 options=list(height=300, width=350))
   Tbl <- gvisTable(Exports, options=list(height=300, width=200))
   plot(gvisMerge(Geo, Tbl, horizontal=TRUE))

   ```

   Plot
   =========================================

  ### Lets plot Fruit vs Year

  ```{r MotionChartExample, results='asis', tidy=FALSE}
  library(googleVis)
  M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, 'Fruit', 'Year', options=list(width=400,      height=350))
  plot(M)

  ```
````